# Link from a pdf document to another pdf document (also ios and pspdfkit)

Tags: ios, pdf, hyperlink, pspdfkit

I have to make an application that displays pdf documents. I will use PSPDFKIT. It works well.
The problem is, in these PDF documents, there are referals to other pdf documents. Alls these pdf's are local and will be bundled in the application.

I've tried all kinds of export settings and ways of linking but I can't open a pdf document by linking to it from another pdf document... Not in the app, not on my Mac.

Does anyone know what I could do? It is really important that the user can read through the pdf and click on links in that pdf, to other pdf's with more information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

With v2.2, I've added support for PDF Link Annotations to other documents. There are several ways to do this, I've documented them on my website: http://pspdfkit.com/documentation.html#annotations. You'll also find an example PDF in the PSPDFCatalog project.